# What is the right way to count filled multi value field values in drupal?

Tags: 7, entities

I've a term reference multi value field.  What is the right way to count filled values which is also portable to D8, D9 etc.

The dsm output shows like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you just trying to count the number of items in a `$node->field_name`, or are you trying to count the inputted values during form validation/submit?

Comment: I mean whenever hook_form_alter is called, I need to count the values.

Answer (score 1):

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('entity_type', $entity);
dpm($wrapper->{FIELD_NAME}->count());
```

Dealing with entity reference field you can get the identifires like this:

```
dpm($wrapper->{FIELD_NAME}->value(array('identifier' => TRUE)));
```

Comment: `$wrapper->{FIELD_NAME}->count()` method doesn't exists.

Comment: Just use it, It does exist. Also the `dpm($wrapper->{FIELD_NAME}->value(array('identifier' => TRUE)));` is good to get all ids from a multivalue field taxonomy reference

Comment: Out of interest, I tested the ->count() it and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using Entity Metadata Wrapper, you can achieve it this way.

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$count = count($wrapper->{FIELD_NAME});
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the type of field, and on when you are trying to retrieve the values.

During `hook_form_alter()` for checkboxes, radios, and select fields, the values you are referring to are typically set via the [#options property](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#options). Example: `$form['artist_tags']['und']['#options']`. You can wrap that in `count()` to get the number of values.

During `hook_form_validate()` or `hook_form_submit()` or a function called from the `$form['#after_build']` property, you will also have access to the number of **selected** values via `$form_state['values']['artist_tags']['und']` (or when `$form_state['submitted']` is TRUE, check `$form_state['input']['artist_tags']['und']`).